# .htaccess code not adding automatic www & https before the url

Tags: .htaccess

This is my .htaccess code:

```
# RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !hashstar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I had added this code to add www & https in the URL forcefully if it is not added. This code worked fine up to some hours ago, but as I tweaked my .htaccess code this code won't work.

In Chrome, Mozilla browsers it's not adding https://www. as a prefix to the URL, it doesn't contain www. or https://www. or http://

I have even reset the cache and data of the Mozilla, chrome browser but the same thing is happening again and again.

Any helps appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enforce `www` and `https` in same rule use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache completely before testing this change.

PS: In case you want to do this ONLY for one specific domain then use 3rd `RewriteCond` as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(hashstar\.com)$ [NC]
```

Comment: don't i need to add # at the line of rewrite engine on ?

Comment: `#` makes it commented. `RewriteEngine On` should remain uncommented,

Comment: Shoot that worked super perfect for me Thanks @anubhava. You seem to have a very good command for .htaccess, my mostly asked .htaccess questions are solved by you, would you like to suggest me a site to make my hand in .htaccess

Comment: I suggest looking at askapache.com and of course Stackoverflow tag of .htaccess :)

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks @anubhava